# Rebuilding Flutter app causes crashes - module 'shared_preferences_ios' not found

Tags: flutter

I've uninstalled a flutter app and tried running it again using `flutter run`. I get curious errors and the latest currently is:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/lechnerio/dev/apps/appname/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error:
    module 'shared_preferences_ios' not found
    @import shared_preferences_ios;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
```

I'm using `shared_preferences: ^2.0.12` in my `pubspec.yaml` and prior to uninstalling the app on the emulator everything worked without an issue.

I tried running `flutter clean` and `flutter run` but I get the same errors.

I tried deleting the `Podfile.lock` and the `/pods` Folder in the iOS Folder and running `flutter run` again, no success.

I tried reinstalling the pods using but no success either.

```
pod deintegrate 
pod setup
pod install
```

running `flutter doctor` shows no issues on the flutter install itself.

running `flutter pub get` manually works.

The full error message:

```
lechnerio@Daniels-MBP appofrandom % flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 mini in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        569ms
Xcode build done.                                            6.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[20531]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both
    /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20247ab90) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
    (0x1068e02c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[20531]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib
    (0x20247abe0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
    (0x1068e0318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/lechnerio/dev/apps/appofrandom/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error:
    module 'shared_preferences_ios' not found
    @import shared_preferences_ios;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 mini.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aparently I was having a broken Podfile. After copying the Podfile of a blank flutter project I was able to `flutter run` again.

The Podfile I'm using now:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I just removed the share_preferences dependencies and reinstalled

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is happen because of broken pod file. Follow below steps to fix issue.

1. Delete Podfile
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pub get`
4. `flutter run`

It works for me.

**OR**

1. Create new flutter project.
2. Copy `Podfile` from new project.
3. Paste to your project `Podfile` which has issue.

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

i search shared_preferences_iOS in my project,and then i found it in build_setting -> other linker flags, i remove it,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).